# How to get nameof() from a property in a collection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the correct `nameof` from the following simplified example:

```
public class Order 
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Sku { get; set; }
}

var order = new Order();
    Requires.That(order.Items.TrueForAll(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.Sku)), nameof(order.Items), "Sku must contain a value");
```

I how do I get the `nameof` to be `nameof(order.Items.Sku)`?

Comment: What is the expected outcome? `nameof(order.Items.Sku)` isn't legal since `Items` has no `Sku` property, of course, and there is no compile-time expression for "the name of the `Sku` property of *any* element in the `Items` list", since that may not universally apply (it just so happens to in this case, but that wouldn't fly generally). You can use `nameof(Item.Sku)`, since you know the types.

Comment: If I understand what you want: You want to retrieve all Sku(Items) of a Order. var order = _context.Order.Include( item => Item.Sku).To List() or FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

There is a [request](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/3570) to support this, and I already gave it my support for what it's worth, but it's against the current language specification.

Answer (score 0):

U can try something like this

```
order.Items.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(x => nameof(x.Sku)).First()
```

Comment: is something wrong in this to achieve since  the language doesn't support it. Person who voted down can expain the reason

Comment: This is not semantically the same thing -- it is not a compile-time constant, it enumerates the collection again, and it fails if the collection is empty. That said, it does avoid writing out the type of `order.Items`, which is one less thing to check on refactoring, so it's not useless.

Comment: I agree as it is not complie time checked, chances are there in case of empty collection. I have updated the post.

Comment: The argument to `DefaultIfEmpty` is unnecessary; `nameof` will operate regardless of the value of `x`. Even then it's quite a big problem that the expression is so unwieldy as to obscure to readers that all we're doing is getting a name. (It becomes even more unwieldy if we have to take into account the possibility that `Items` is `null`, which `nameof` wouldn't care about.)

Comment: I'm afraid without value in defaultorempty clause, when collection is empty. Select clause would not iterate and hence we end up getting nothing. Well just to get name of a property this seems quite a lot of boilerplate code.

Comment: I didn't say `DefaultOrEmpty` was unnecessary, but the *argument* is: `order.Items.DefaultIfEmpty().Select(x => nameof(x.Sku)).First()` works just as well, even though `x` is `null`. In fact, it works better since there's no construction of an `Item` just to get a name.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly this isn't possible.

Given that you know you are processing `Item` instances your best bet is to use `nameof(Item.Sku)` instead.