# How can i get nameof sub entity if it is in a list?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

If i want to get name of sub entity / sub property i can just: `nameof(ClassName.Entity.SubProperty)` but what if Entity is actually a list? `nameof(ClassName.Entity.Select(x => x.SubProperty)` doesn't work because i get "expression does not have a name" error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get nameof() from a property in a collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471840/how-to-get-nameof-from-a-property-in-a-collection)

Comment: yeah, i use it as parameter for include (method takes string[]) thats why i can't use theninclude and wanted to somehow get name using nameof.

Answer (score 1):

The list would contain items of some type, like `List<MyType>`. In that case just write `nameof(MyType.SubProperty)`

Comment: Oh, thats a good idea, but i use this string in Include in EF Core (method takes string[] parameter and passes it to include inside foreach).

Comment: `new string[] {nameof(MyType.SubProperty)}`

Comment: yeah thats how i pass this to my method, but it throws "invalid include path"

Comment: ah ok, i managed to make it work, its nameof(ClassName.Entity) + "." + nameof(EntityClass.Property)